# How to customize the tab in Android like this?

Tags: android

I am new in android development and I am working on the TabHost, I need to customize the tabs following  is the screen shot link how i want to show my tabs.

[image]

text in starting should be dynamic and can change based on the tabs click
In screen shot i have selected chat if I select home the text should change to Home etc.

please help me to solve this out thanks...

Answer (score 0):

That's called an ActionBar. If you're developing under 3.0 or higher it's standard. If you want to support earlier versious, you can check Greendroid or ActionBar Sherlock libraries ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am developing on Google2.2

Answer (score 0):

This is an ActionBar if I am not wrong, you can use **ActionBarSherlock** for your app it's located [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)